# Add horizontal spaces to UISearchBar and cancelButton in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add spaces for UISearchBar. But when cancel button pressed spaces destroyed. I tried with different frames and constraints, but nothing works.[This is how it looks after cancel clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4na4.png)

Comment: Are you using showsCancelButton? Or do you want to create a custom button?

Comment: No, I don't want custom button. But I don't understand why constraints don't work with button. When cancel button hidden - ok, but when I tap on UISearchBar, cancel button appears and breaks right constraint.

Answer (score 0):

So. I solved this problem to create container (UIView) for searchBar and add searchBar to container and container to navBar. After that called searchBar.sizeToFit() and searchBar became as big as container. I don't know is this right way, but it works.